# How to make 404 pages not write an error log?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

In our philosophy, an error log is always caused by a programmer error.

In Play 1.2.x, prod mode, any access to a non-existing page will trigger an error log:

```
ERROR (play) ~ 
MyController.myAction action not found
Action not found
Action MyController.myAction could not be found. Error raised is No method public static void myAction() was found in class controllers.MyController
play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException: Action MyController.myAction not found
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:604)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.resolve(ActionInvoker.java:85)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No method public static void myAction() was found in class controllers.MyController
```

How can I configure Play not to issue an error log in this cases? Maybe a `WARN` log level, at most?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for logging this is located in ActionInvoker.java(play 1.2.5RC4):

```
catch (ActionNotFoundException e) {
            Logger.error(e, "%s action not found", e.getAction());
            throw new NotFound(String.format("%s action not found", e.getAction()));
        }
```

So it seems there is no way to adjust the logging level of the ActionNotFoundException. I agree that this should not be at the 'error' level. I would recommend opening up a ticket at https://play.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

While not the most elegant of solutions, you can use the `ExpressionFilter` class from the Apache log4j Extras package to filter these exceptions out of your default error log with the following changes:

**dependencies.yml**:

```
- log4j -> apache-log4j-extras 1.2.17:
    transitive: false
```

**<logging>.conf**:

```
log4j.appender.<appender>.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter
log4j.appender.<appender>.filter.1.expression=EXCEPTION ~= play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException
log4j.appender.<appender>.filter.1.acceptOnMatch=false
```

This also allows you to redirect those specific messages to a separate destination by creating a new log4j appender and inverting the `acceptOnMatch` property in the above rule to only accept logging for the `ActionNotFound` exception.